# What is "pendant natural" in this UN report?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I lighted upon a sentence in a [United Nations report](http://docstore.ohchr.org/SelfServices/FilesHandler.ashx?enc=6QkG1d%2FPPRiCAqhKb7yhsgA84bcFRy75ulvS2cmS%2F%2BjVQ%2F7hMZ5ysMKntMSi3EwZkTnlq7f%2FnXMK0H6V0XwLdeGyy3HUbf7hNOxFA%2F%2Fa9W9Xzy5KlhhO%2BWjCrIsDOtmr) of Italy, written in English:

> On a more general note, this issue will continue to be the subject of attention during the current Legislature, of which the ***pendant natural*** is the sharing of parental responsibility in case of divorce.

The context is about family, children, and adoption, and the term *pendant natural* is in italics in the original text. Google doesn't seem to be of any help in figuring out what this term means. It doesn't seem to be idiomatic. What does it mean?

Comment: It's not familiar to me.  I wonder if it isn't a transliteration of an Italian or Latin term.

Comment: In a Google search, once you remove references to lighting, what seems to be left are ads for jewellery.

Comment: Looks like French to me: "the natural counterpart"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Yep, that's what I found.  There were hints of a particular gemstone by that name, but it was hard to tell if it was just jumbled words in the ads.

Comment: As the OP stated,  in the original document "pendant natural" is italicized, strongly suggesting that the author considers it a foreign term to English.  StoneyB's suggestion is likely the best you're going to do, unless someone recognizes it as an idiom in some language.

Comment: I'm voting to close; this question does not appear to be about the English language.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd argue loanwords and their usage are part and parcel of the English language, especially formal English writing. Case in point and exemplary: well, this question.

Comment: Of course loanwords are part and parcel of the English language. By definition, they have been accepted into the lexis. 'Pendant natural', not appearing in any dictionary and apparently not used in the sense you suggest on the internet, can't be claimed to be a loan word. The 'U' in ELU stands for usage. Standard usage, not typographical errors or one-off uses of foreign terms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, this doesn't make much sense. Consider such a question as "Is this usage of participial phrases correct?" Would you also jump to a closevote on that question? You have to have a correct usage against which incorrect ones can be compared and identified. It's not like people want to ask about incorrectness and there's specific site where people ask things that might be incorrect just so ELU won't get _contaminated._ "not used in the sense you suggest on the internet" I have no idea why you mean by that.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Just because there is a misspelling doesn't mean the term at issue is not worth a question. There has been testimony in this discussion that attests to the term in question being a widely used legalese term in English documents. **Consider two things: 1) Had my cited source used the correct spelling, I would also have been at sea about its meaning, and would've come here and asked about it all the same. 2) Now that we've learned there's a misspelling, what do you want me to do? Delete this question and post another one with _pendant naturel_?**

Comment: The phrase does not occur in any English dictionary I am aware of. I can't find any mention of the legal sense on the internet. You have accepted an answer stating that it is a French term.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth: Ohhh, I see what you are taking issue with. But there has been testimony (e.g. by @Tonny) of its currency in English. Are you calling that into doubt? Are you suggesting this question be migrated to the French SE site? Since lengthy back-and-forth comments are not encouraged on SE, I will leave it at that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unless the author is using a Spanish or Portuguese expression, it's a typographical error in the French [*pendant naturel*](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/le+pendant+naturel.html), meaning ‘natural counterpart or complement’, i.e., that discussing one topic will naturally lead to another. An [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pendant%20naturel&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpendant%20naturel%3B%2Cc0) suggests it is a not uncommon expression in that language.

> Le pendant naturel de la lutte contre le racisme est le dialogue interculturel qui est une des composantes essentielles …
>   *The natural counterpart of the fight against racism is intercultural dialogue, which is one of the essential components …*

Without looking at the French, an English speaker would likely say “a natural extension.” Same idea, different spatial metaphor.

Comment: Yeah, I tried Googling "pendant naturale", as an attempt at a French/Italian spelling, but didn't try "pendant naturel".

Comment: I got a number of hits for Spanish and Portuguese _pendant natural_ in Google Books with the same meaning as the French _pendant naturel_, but nothing for Italian _pendente naturale_. I would surmise that Sp and Port borrowed from Fr, but It didn't.

Comment: @KarlG I'm a Portuguese native speaker and I can assure you that *pendant* doesn't exist in Portuguese, even less the expression *"pendant natural"*... so, nothing borrowed.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: 1. O movimento modernista que começara a delinear-se no sul tinha nele o pendant natural e por excelência no nordeste.  2. Ora, o illustre botânico de Angola é, por um pendant natural da sua educação technica, um decidido propagandista da introducção de novas espécies e variedades de productôres de café em Cazengo e Golungo.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado It's basically impossible to say something doesn't exist. Most languages have 3-10x as many words as the average educated speaker knows. I would have also chalked it up to French though.

Comment: @KarlG Can you provide the link for those quotes? They are full of words (illustre, technica) whose spell has changed decades ago.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Of course, I chose my words badly: it's not common, it's not normally used and it's not present in any important dictionary.

Comment: See if this works. I'm on an iPad and can't switch tabs in a browser and retain content. The first hit is Spanish, one totally irrelevant German book, and the rest are Portuguese: https://www.google.de/search?q=%22pendant+natural%22&rlz=1C9BKJA_enDE701DE701&tbm=bks&prmd=sivn&ei=gXfQWuXwCqjm6AT544DADw&start=30&sa=N&biw=1024&bih=748&dpr=1

Comment: @KarlG Thanks, but that's funny: there is **no** Portuguese book in the link you sent! Maybe when you're on your computer you can check it again. Anyway, my point is just that *pendant* is a gallicism, it's not Portuguese, and those authors just translated the *naturel* for *natural*, keeping the *pendant* in the original French.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: It would be far easier if you'd just query Google Books yourself for the string "pendant natural."

Comment: @KarlG I did that before posting my first comment, just to be sure, and I found nothing. Anyway, you guys are right, I'm wrong, *pendant natural* is Portuguese, and let's forget about this and move on...

Comment: According to my girlfriend (who is a professional translator specializing in French/English legal and contract documents) the French expression as stated is legalese jargon and as such appears in English official documents as well. In this case it seems the author (or more likely his spell-checker) mangled the French word "naturel" and replaced it with "natural". My spell-checker is trying to do the same thing while writing this.

Comment: @Tonny Your comment contains some useful information. Unfortunately it gets buried. I think your comment has the potential of a stand-alone answer, or at least a comment under the question as it is a direct response to my question. I almost missed your comment.

Comment: @Tonny: I didn't find any specifically legal usage, but the NGram query yielded a large number of hits from a wide variety of fields.

Answer (score 5):

Per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pendant), one meaning of "pendant" is "counterpart" or "companion piece". So in this case, the text seems to be saying *"[the sharing of parental responsibility]* is an issue that will naturally be considered alongside *[whatever issue they were talking about before the quoted text]".*

Comment: This is what I was thinking (saw the same definition), but couldn't find any uses of it (aside from light fixtures and jewelry).